# Pausing between cout statements for a set duration

Tags: c++, cout

I wrote a Blackjack progrram where the user goes first and can continue to take hits until his total is above 21. Then I did the same for the cpu, who would be the dealer/the house in real blackjack. It works great. The user side of the program works to perfection. What i want to do is have the two original cards be printed to the screen, pause for a few seconds, and then continue if the house takes a hit. Currently, all of the text for the house's turn bombards the screen. I want to add pauses so it slows the print process by cout statement. How would i go about doing this??

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for

Comment: Plus one for asking and not writing a tight loop.

Answer (score 3):

C++11 solution

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello waiter" << std::endl;
    std::chrono::milliseconds dura( 2000 );
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( dura );
    std::cout << "Waited 2000 ms\n";
}
```